# error message "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <FirstTabViewController: 0x7ae82a10>"

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem while I apply this code on

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
 UINavigationController *nav=(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController;
    [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

when select index at 0 error message xcode give "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ." and my all tabbar getting freeze.please help me out.Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep getting "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController>" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919616/keep-getting-unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-viewcont)

Comment: [Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UITabBarController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563473/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: thank you this will solve my problem :)